# Using a function to select a service which inherits from a base service in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a function that I have tried to write out like this:

```
    selectService():BaseService {
        let url = 'None';
        chrome.tabs.getCurrent((tab?:Tab) => {
            if (typeof tab !== 'undefined' && typeof tab.url !== 'undefined'){
                url = tab.url;
            }
        });
        if (url.includes('site1')) {
            return Service1;
        } else if(url.includes('site2')){
            return Service2;
        } else {
            return Service3;
        }
    }
```

`Service1`, `Service2`, and `Service3` all extend `BaseService`.

I have the following issue: Type 'typeof Service1' is missing the following properties from type 'BaseService': text, usersCases and 5 more. Can I not just use the base class as the return type?

Comment: Are you trying to return a type or object/instance of the service here? When you write return type is BaseService it is expecting a object of that type.

Comment: Show in your question also how are `Service1, Service2, Service3` exactly defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to return the service class instead of an instance of that service. Return types in typescript are used to describe the type of the return value, instead of the return value itself. When returning an instance, the type resolves to a class. However, the same is not true when returning a class. You may try the following in the [TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) to understand this better.

```js
class Foo {
    showMessage() {
        console.log("I am Foo");
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo { }

class Baz extends Foo { }

class Qux {
    rebel() {
        console.log("I am not Foo");
    }
}

const classFactory = (selector: 'Bar' | 'Baz'): typeof Foo => {
    if (selector === 'Bar') {
        return Bar;
    } else if (selector === 'Baz') {
        return Baz;
    } else {
        return Qux;
    }
}

const instanceFactory = (selector: 'Bar' | 'Baz'): Foo => {
    if (selector === 'Bar') {
        return new Bar();
    } else if (selector === 'Baz') {
        return new Baz();
    } else {
        return new Qux();
    }
}
```